# How to configure a Website that auth's for YouTube credentials to be used by console application?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Ultimately, I am trying to upload a YouTube video on behalf of a user who has authorized my site / application to do so.

I have a website where a user authorizes the website to use the user's YouTube credentials.  The website then properly stores the credentials after the user has authorized (YouTube Data API v3).  The problem is, these credentials are desired to be used by a server process, which for all purposes would be considered a console application.

When adding credentials to my project on the Google API Manager, however, I can either do a Web Browser, Web Server, (and others) OR "other UI (Windows)".  But I cannot do BOTH.  I believe I need both because the user authorizes through the website, but the console process uses the credentials.

But even if I have an answer for that above, how do I pass the USER'S credentials to the console app using the sample code that they show in the samples?

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }
```

It seems like this code is used more for storing the credentials somewhere on the Windows file system to be retrieved later, like a cache.  But I'm storing these "authorized" values in a database already, and would like to retrieve them and act on the behalf of that user.

I hope this makes sense, and I apologize if it rambled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background:**

The Google .NET client library by default stores the credentials for the users in `%AppData%` the field where you have "user" is how its is storing it.

**Example:**

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretsJsonFilePath
                                   ,FileMode.Open
                                   ,FileAccess.Read))
{   
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
        "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")                               
    ).Result;
}
```

Assuming the user clicks accept on the authentication request screen, a new file will be created in that directory with the following structure:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-LookIAmAUniqueUser.TokenResponse-LookIAmAUniqueUser
```

Each user will have their own file you change a user by changing the "LookIAmAUniqueUser" value.

**Solution one:**

Identify your users differently so that you know you are loading me vs you. Just by changing the "user" parameter, it will load the one needed or ask the user for authentication if it can't find it.

**Solution two:**

By default the library uses [FileDataStore](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a5288c4493a12791b46f7142efacb83c4fcacf58/Src/Support/GoogleApis.DotNet4/Apis/Util/Store/FileDataStore.cs) that's why I have it in mine and you don't have it in yours.  If you are storing the credentials someplace else say the refresh token in the database along with your user information.   You can create your own implementation of [IDataStore](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a5288c4493a12791b46f7142efacb83c4fcacf58/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Core/Apis/Util/Store/IDataStore.cs) which will load the credentials from there.

My article on FileDataStore might help you understand what its doing.  [Google .NET – FileDataStore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)  sorry I haven't had time to create a article on creating an implementation of IDataStore, however I might have an example or two laying around depends really on where you are storing those credentials

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I was looking for, however, does anyone else find this to be archaic and limiting?  Forcing the need to create folders and files based upon users?  **Is there a way to call all of this stuff manually through assembling posts, forms, and parameters?**

Comment: In your example from your link I'm not seeing a method by which you can obtain the necessary keys via database.  Do you have such an example?

Comment: Like I said you can create your own implementation of iDatastore and load it from anywhere.   I have a version that stored it all in the database for example.

Comment: https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Authentication there is a db one in there it's old code sorry I really need to make a better example

Comment: THANKS!  One final question - When adding credentials to my project on the Google API Manager, I can either do a Web Browser, Web Server, (and others) OR "other UI (Windows)".  While the user would "authorize" via the website, the console application would use the credentials.  So which one of those do I set this up as in the Google Dashboard?  Web? Application?

Comment: If you can find me through my website or github email me and I can walk you through hacking it maybe ;) to hard to explain that in a comment I may try and edit the question in the morning if I remember